# Find the sums of unique levels of a column and add them as new rows in the dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and based on the unique levels of the `Vaccination.YearWeek` (2) column I would like to add two new rows with the sums of all countries per `Vaccination.YearWeek`. The `Vaccination.YearWeek` will be the relative `Vaccination.YearWeek` `(2020-W52)` ,the `Country` will be named `Total-Vaccination.YearWeek (Total-2020-W52)` and the Uptake first dose % will show the total of all countries. The number of unique levels may be dynamic so I cannot just manually put those rows there.

```
d1<-data.frame(structure(list(Vaccination.YearWeek = c("2020-W52", "2020-W52", 
                                            "2020-W52", "2020-W52", "2020-W52", "2020-W52", "2020-W52", "2020-W52", 
                                            "2020-W52", "2020-W52", "2020-W52", "2020-W52", "2020-W52", "2020-W52", 
                                            "2020-W52", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", 
                                            "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", 
                                            "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", 
                                            "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", 
                                            "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53", "2020-W53"), Country = c("EU/EEA", 
                                                                                                         "Czechia", "Estonia", "Finland", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", 
                                                                                                         "Italy", "Lithuania", "Malta", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", 
                                                                                                         "Slovenia", "Sweden", "EU/EEA", "Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", 
                                                                                                         "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", 
                                                                                                         "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", 
                                                                                                         "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Norway", 
                                                                                                         "Poland", "Portugal", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden"), `Uptake first dose (%)` = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 1, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.1, 1.8, 0.1, 0.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: one for every week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to group by 'Vaccination.YearWeek' and use `adorn_totals`

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
d1 %>% 
  select(Country, everything()) %>% 
  group_by(Vaccination.YearWeek) %>%
  group_map(~ .x %>%
              adorn_totals(), .keep = TRUE)  %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  mutate(Country = case_when(Country == 'Total'
   ~ str_c('Total-', lag(Vaccination.YearWeek)), TRUE ~ Country ),
  Vaccination.YearWeek = na_if(Vaccination.YearWeek, "-")) %>%
  fill(Vaccination.YearWeek) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
          Country Vaccination.YearWeek Uptake.first.dose....
         EU/EEA             2020-W52                   0.0
        Czechia             2020-W52                   0.0
        Estonia             2020-W52                   0.0
        Finland             2020-W52                   0.0
        Germany             2020-W52                   0.0
         Greece             2020-W52                   0.0
        Hungary             2020-W52                   0.0
          Italy             2020-W52                   0.0
      Lithuania             2020-W52                   0.1
          Malta             2020-W52                   0.0
         Norway             2020-W52                   0.0
         Poland             2020-W52                   0.0
       Portugal             2020-W52                   0.1
       Slovenia             2020-W52                   0.3
         Sweden             2020-W52                   0.0
 Total-2020-W52             2020-W52                   0.5
         EU/EEA             2020-W53                   0.2
        Austria             2020-W53                   0.1
        Belgium             2020-W53                   0.0
       Bulgaria             2020-W53                   0.1
        Croatia             2020-W53                   0.4
         Cyprus             2020-W53                   0.4
        Czechia             2020-W53                   0.2
        Denmark             2020-W53                   1.0
        Estonia             2020-W53                   0.0
        Finland             2020-W53                   0.1
         France             2020-W53                   0.0
        Germany             2020-W53                   0.4
         Greece             2020-W53                   0.0
        Hungary             2020-W53                   0.1
        Iceland             2020-W53                   1.8
        Ireland             2020-W53                   0.1
          Italy             2020-W53                   0.2
         Latvia             2020-W53                   0.1
      Lithuania             2020-W53                   0.4
     Luxembourg             2020-W53                   0.2
          Malta             2020-W53                   0.4
         Norway             2020-W53                   0.1
         Poland             2020-W53                   0.2
       Portugal             2020-W53                   0.4
       Slovenia             2020-W53                   0.7
          Spain             2020-W53                   0.2
         Sweden             2020-W53                   0.2
 Total-2020-W53             2020-W53                   8.0
```

---

Or another option is `group_map` with `add_row`

```
d1 %>% 
    group_by(Vaccination.YearWeek) %>% 
    group_map(~  .x %>% 
        add_row(Vaccination.YearWeek = str_c('Total-', last(.x$Vaccination.YearWeek),
         Country = last(.x$Country),
         `Uptake.first.dose....` = sum(.x$`Uptake.first.dose....`, na.rm = TRUE))), 
         .keep = TRUE) %>%
    bind_rows
# A tibble: 44 x 3
   Vaccination.YearWeek Country   Uptake.first.dose....
   <chr>                <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 2020-W52             EU/EEA                      0  
 2 2020-W52             Czechia                     0  
 3 2020-W52             Estonia                     0  
 4 2020-W52             Finland                     0  
 5 2020-W52             Germany                     0  
 6 2020-W52             Greece                      0  
 7 2020-W52             Hungary                     0  
 8 2020-W52             Italy                       0  
 9 2020-W52             Lithuania                   0.1
10 2020-W52             Malta                       0  
# … with 34 more rows
```

Comment: the total should have the week name in relative column as well, not a "-"

Comment: That is fixed with `fill`

Comment: @MartinGal it have some utility functions `clean_names`, and summarisation with `adorn_totals`, `adorn_percentages` etc

Comment: @akrun Those `adorn`-functions seem quite useful! Learned - again - some great new function from you. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `stringr`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

d1 %>%
  group_by(Vaccination.YearWeek) %>%
  summarise(`Uptake.first.dose....`=sum(Uptake.first.dose....)) %>%
  mutate(Country = paste0("ZZ_Total-Vaccination.YearWeek (Total-", Vaccination.YearWeek,")")) %>%
  select(1, 3, 2) %>%
  bind_rows(d1) %>%
  arrange(Vaccination.YearWeek, Country) %>%
  mutate(Country = str_remove(Country, "ZZ_"))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 44 x 3
   Vaccination.YearWeek Country                                     Uptake.first.dose....
   <chr>                <chr>                                                       <dbl>
 1 2020-W52             Czechia                                                       0  
 2 2020-W52             Estonia                                                       0  
 3 2020-W52             EU/EEA                                                        0  
 4 2020-W52             Finland                                                       0  
 5 2020-W52             Germany                                                       0  
 6 2020-W52             Greece                                                        0  
 7 2020-W52             Hungary                                                       0  
 8 2020-W52             Italy                                                         0  
 9 2020-W52             Lithuania                                                     0.1
10 2020-W52             Malta                                                         0  
11 2020-W52             Norway                                                        0  
12 2020-W52             Poland                                                        0  
13 2020-W52             Portugal                                                      0.1
14 2020-W52             Slovenia                                                      0.3
15 2020-W52             Sweden                                                        0  
16 2020-W52             Total-Vaccination.YearWeek (Total-2020-W52)                   0.5
17 2020-W53             Austria                                                       0.1
18 2020-W53             Belgium                                                       0  
19 2020-W53             Bulgaria                                                      0.1
20 2020-W53             Croatia                                                       0.4
21 2020-W53             Cyprus                                                        0.4
22 2020-W53             Czechia                                                       0.2
23 2020-W53             Denmark                                                       1  
24 2020-W53             Estonia                                                       0  
25 2020-W53             EU/EEA                                                        0.2
26 2020-W53             Finland                                                       0.1
27 2020-W53             France                                                        0  
28 2020-W53             Germany                                                       0.4
29 2020-W53             Greece                                                        0  
30 2020-W53             Hungary                                                       0.1
31 2020-W53             Iceland                                                       1.8
32 2020-W53             Ireland                                                       0.1
33 2020-W53             Italy                                                         0.2
34 2020-W53             Latvia                                                        0.1
35 2020-W53             Lithuania                                                     0.4
36 2020-W53             Luxembourg                                                    0.2
37 2020-W53             Malta                                                         0.4
38 2020-W53             Norway                                                        0.1
39 2020-W53             Poland                                                        0.2
40 2020-W53             Portugal                                                      0.4
41 2020-W53             Slovenia                                                      0.7
42 2020-W53             Spain                                                         0.2
43 2020-W53             Sweden                                                        0.2
44 2020-W53             Total-Vaccination.YearWeek (Total-2020-W53)                   8
```